# Having API route read a file in Next.js in the app directory

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes

I've struggled with everything in Nextjs. Even the basic things don't work for me.
This simple example is an API call where it returns logged in if 'Me' is entered, and it's supposed to return a message read from `mydata.txt`. The file read is breaking it, if `msg` is hardcoded it works!

```js
app/api/myapi.js

var fs = require('fs');
export default function handler(req, res) {
  var msg = fs.readFileSync("mydata.txt")
  if(req.body=="Me"){ res.status(200).json({ message: `Logged in` }) }
  else{ res.status(200).json({ message: `Error ${msg}` })  } 
}
```

In the `index.html`, I try and fetch the response and alert it.
`mydata.txt` file has the line `"Not logged in"`
(`mydata.txt` is in the `app/api` directory, I also tried putting it in the root directory.)

The errors are always:

> POST https://basicapi.vercel.app/api/myapi 404 (Not Found)
> VM155:1  Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I tried moving the `mydata.txt` file to different places. When `msg` was hardcoded it worked as expected.

Comment: It should be `app/api/route.js` for a route handler in the app directory. Also, the route handler should follow a specific syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76214029/no-http-methods-exported-in-export-a-named-export-for-each-http-method/76215680#76215680

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing app router (new with NextJS 13) and page router. They require different styles and even the NextJS documentation separated the docs according to router type the project based on.

If you're using **page router**:

- Parent folder should be `page`
- You can continue using your current file, just change the path to `/pages/api/myapi.js`

If you're using **app router:**

- Parent folder should be `app`
- The file should be named `route.js`. For your case, the path should be `/app/api/myapi/route.js`
- Handler functions must be named as HTTP verbs e.g. GET, POST etc, each exported.
- Also parameters of the handler are not standard express requests and response in handlers. In TypeScript, the handler takes an object with type of `NextRequest`, different than the `express.Request`

If you want to continue with the app router, then you need to change your code.