# next 13.4 api route/server action

Tags: forms, next.js

I am creating an admin panel with next 13.4 and I am trying to figure out why I am getting a 405 error

```
export default function NewProduct() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const[price, setPrice] = useState('');
  async function createProduct(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = {title,description, price};
    //console.log(data)
    await axios.post("/api/products", data);
  }
    return (
        <Layout>
          <form onSubmit={createProduct}>
            <h1>new product</h1>
            <label>Product name</label>
            <input 
              type='text'
              placeholder="product name"
              value={title} 
              onChange={(ev) => setTitle(ev.target.value)}
            />
            <label>description</label>
            <textarea
            placeholder="description"
            value={description}
            onChange={(ev) => setDescription(ev.target.value)}
            />
            <label>
              price (in USD)
            </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="price"
              value={price}
              onChange={(ev) => setPrice(ev.target.value)}
            />
            <button
             type="submit"
              className="btn-primary">
              Save product
            </button>
          </form>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

the axios post request works but I get this in developer tools: xhr.js:251 POST http://localhost:3000/api/products 405 (Method Not Allowed)

my api/products:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    res.json(req.method)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No HTTP methods exported in '...'. Export a named export for each HTTP method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76214029/no-http-methods-exported-in-export-a-named-export-for-each-http-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send an `object` to an `API`, you have to convert it to `JSON`.

Recommended way is converting the obj to json and save it in `cookies`, then sending it to the API.

If you want to have a little security option, first sign the json obj with a **public key** and save it in cookies (JWT). Then send it to API and decrypt it in API and you can use it.

Don't forget if you receive a json, you have to parse it if you want to use like an obj in API.